# Is it possible to retrieve a Javascript variable from a script to use it in R

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, leaflet, shinyjs

my question is in the title, I'm currently developing a shiny App, and as I'm trying to use a leaflet plugin that hasn't been translated in a R package at the moment, I'm using a var map in a js script (I use this script in my UI.R), the fact is that I would like in the server part to be able to communicate with this map, with for exemple a leaflet proxy to add tiles on it, but I didn't manage to make the server part communicate with that Js var...

Maybe if a have a clew of what's the problem you could help me a lot.!

Thanks.

Comment: might want to check out https://github.com/daattali/shinyjs, or look at Dean's code for timevis https://github.com/daattali/timevis/blob/master/inst/htmlwidgets/timevis.js#L234-L252

Comment: If I have understand well enough the timevis code from Dean, he is using the Js function Shiny.onInputChange() to link the Js var to a R var, the thing is when I'm using this function, in the console I get a message saying this "Shiny.onInputChange is not a function" :((

Comment: there is no mechanism to control JS from R unless you have a connection, generally Shiny.  Without a connection, the JS and R know nothing of each other.

Comment: Oh so it's impossible to interact with the map created with a Js cmd, I mean in shiny with a cmd like leafletproxy to add polygons and stuff?

Comment: no, in Shiny, this is possible, but your comment `Shiny.onInputChange` is not a function means that you either do not have `shiny.js` or that you have not waited for Shiny to connect https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/js-events.html

Comment: Thank you for the tip, i don't get this error now, but there is another one, lol, it says "Map container is already initialized." I don't get it... ><

Comment: There is also another error, which is "data.options is undefined", so I think the error might come from this too... I think we nearly reach the goal..

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do it.

#### ui.R

```
tags$script(src="demo.js")
```

#### demo.js

```
var map = ...
setTimeout(function() {
    Shiny.onInputChange("mapInR", map);
}, 10);
```

Now you can pass the value of map from javascript to R.

In **server.R** you just need to check for javascript value **map** as:

```
server <- function(input, output) {
    useMapInR <- reactive({ input$mapInR })
}
```

Now whenever value of **map** changes in javascript it will get reflected in **useMapInR**.